# django rest framework view, unicode object has not attribute isoformat

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-rest-framework

I'm using the django rest framework to access data from a read only database via my browser. The url I'm visiting is:

```
domain.com/api/data
```

I'm getting the error:

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'isoformat'
exception location: *dirs*/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py in to_representation, line 1141
```

This is my URLs file:

```
from pypackage.api import views as api_views
api_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
api_router.register('data', api_views.DataViewSet)

urlpatterns += [
    url('^api/', include(api_router.urls))
]
```

and my framework views file:

```
class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ReadOnlyTable.objects.values('data1', 'data2', 'data3').distinct().order_by('data3')
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
```

and serizlizers.py

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ReadOnlyTable
        fields = ('data1', 'data2', 'data3')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should set an actual queryset here `queryset = ReadOnlyTable.objects.values('data1', 'data2', 'data3').distinct().order_by('data3')`, you are passing a list of dicts.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
queryset = ReadOnlyTable.objects.values('data1', 'data2', 'data3').distinct().order_by('data3')
```

You should use an actual queryset instead, since `.values` returns a list of dicts, so you could do something like:

```
queryset = ReadOnlyTable.objects.distinct('data1', 'data2', 'data3').order_by('data3')
```

take in mind you can do `.distinct(...fields...)` if you are using PostgreSQL

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. `ReadOnlyTable.objects.all()` also returns the same error.

Comment: Then you have more that one issue, but undoubtedly the one i posted is one of them, because `to_representation` is failing due to the iteration is over a list of strings, instead a list of ReadOnlyTable instances